# Pytest parametrize passing function name as a parameter

Tags: pytest, pytest-mock, parametrized-testing

I am trying to get function name as a parameter in pytest parametrize but getting the error *'str' object is not callable* since it passes as a string.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_something(mocker, function_name, value):
    return mocker.patch(function_name, return_value = value)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "expected, value, function_name", 
    [(100001, 100008, "one_adder")],
)
def test_create_uniq_no(expected, function_name, value):
    assert expected == function_name(value)
```

The patch part is working when i write the function name manually in mocker.patch, but that would require me to write every function/class name in order to test them. How can i have the function name as a parameter?

I tried using globals but got a key error.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_something(mocker, function_name, value):
    return mocker.patch(function_name, return_value = value)

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "expected, value, function_name", 
    [(100001, 100008, "one_adder")],
)
def test_some_func(expected, function_name, value):
    func = globals()[function_name]
    assert expected == func(value)
```

Comment: Either you pass the function instead of the function name, or you call it using `globals` (provided it as a global function), e.g. `globals()[function_name](value)`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, i had tried to call using globals, but that gave me a key error, which is reasonable. I also tried using dictionary, then the error stays the same. I am thinking it might be about the process of parameterizing.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Also, why do you think the KeyError is reasonable? Isn't your function global?

Comment: I edited the question. For key error, i thought that it's reasonable because function hasn't been parameterized yet.

Comment: I may not understand your code. I expect that in your example a function `one_adder`  exists, and using your code without the patch works fine for me provided the function indeed returns the expected value for the given input value. With the patching, however (which has to be adapted to include the correct module, by the way), I see no sense in the code: you patch a function to return a specific value, and then check that the mock returns that value - I don't see how that will work if `value` and `expected` are different, and what it will actually test.

Comment: This code is a part of a larger project, and one adder in original actually creates some kind of order ID by adding one to a long number, even then it doesn't make sense, i know. This assignment was given to me in an internship, and the end goal was to make a test function that gets everything as parameters. As of now this block of code tests, well, if Python knows math.

Comment: Hm, well, I still don't understand why you need the mock (I understand you want to test the function, not mock it), and why the code doesn't work for you.

Comment: As I wrote, you need to add the correct module to the patching, so provided your function is in the same module, you should use something like `mocker.patch(f"{__name__}.{function_name}", return_value=value)`. It looks like you are adding the module to the function name instead - that won't work with `globals`.

Comment: You wrote the comment the same time as i figured it out. Yes, it is impossible to get one string for both, because patching requires the full path and calling the function or using globals requires  less. I'm gonna need to change the method entirely. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Still one remark: It would be cleaner to use the function instead of the function name as a parameter, so you don't need `globals` and could just call the function. You would have to use `function.__name__` in the patch string instead.